# Failed to "ack" for 3000 message(s). Reason: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 524288 bytes

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am using Node JS client for Google PubSub (RPC StreamingPullRequest API) with flow control.  My subscription options look like that:

```
 {
      streamingOptions: {
        // decrease this to reduce re-deliveries
        maxStreams: 2, // default: 5
      },
      flowControl: {
        allowExcessMessages: false,
        maxMessages: 4000, // No issues at 2000
      },
    },
```

I reduced maxStreams from 5 (default) to 2 to reduce re-deliveries, as mentioned [here in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/pubsub/subscription-class).  When I set the maxMessages to 4000, I get the following debug warning, which causes re-deliveries of messages:

```
Pubsub subscription received debug message: Failed to "ack" for 3000 message(s). Reason: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 524288 bytes.
```

Why am I getting the warning, and how can I increase the payload size?

Comment: Hi @Aimn, as per this similar github [link1](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/1366#issuecomment-894205726) and [link2](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/pull/65), if you send too many ackIds with one request you may get this error. So, try to give the `maxmessages` as 2500 or 3000 and let me know if this helps you or not ?

Comment: Hi @DhirajSingh, when you say increase maxMessages are you referring to the flowControl options?  because I have already increased that to 4000 but without any luck.  I tried flowControl.maxMessages of 2500, the debug warning goes away.  I have also changed the batching.maxMessages options to 4100 but still getting the same error.  So the question, how can I send 4000 acks without any problems?

Comment: As recommended by @Kamal, it appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue or you can raise an issue in [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues).

Answer (score 0):

The client library should generally ensure that requests do not exceed the size limit, regardless of flow control limits. If that is not happening and you are getting an error like this, you should put in an issue in the [Node library GitHub repository](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues) so that it can be investigated.

Comment: Hi @KamalAboulHosn,  What do you mean by the size limit?  How do I change it?

Comment: There error you are getting is `Request payload size exceeds the limit: 524288 bytes,` so the payload size limit. This is not a property you should need to configure, which is why I recommend entering an issue.

Comment: I will do that as soon as I can, as I am traveling right now. Thanks for your help.